# char vs varchar for french accents (multibyte characters)

Tags: mysql, performance, char, varchar

I will have a large database with words, and one column
of the table would have a maximum of 3 letters however
there will be some french accents like â, ê, î, ô, û,

An example would be Having a column that would possibly have
[id][column2]
1   a
2   b
3   vf
4   êf
5   t

So they wont be fixed at all times, and sometimes some of the rows will
have accent characters, which to my knowledge require one more byte.

I'm thinking what would be the best option to specify for that column?
CHAR might be faster, because they will need 3 bytes max at every time
but often times there will be stored 1-2 bytes

On the other hand VARCHAR is variable length, and I dont have to specify anything
But I have read that char is better for performance, as I will be reading columns
words very often.

What do you think is best? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VARCHAR` unless you're talking about fixed length fields like ISO country codes that are *guaranteed* to be a certain length.

Remember *characters* and *bytes* are not the same thing. The character set for this column and/or table and/or connection and/or the original string will have an impact on what's actually stored. In some character sets a character like `é` is one byte, and in others, like UTF-8, it's two. Other characters like  will be three or four bytes and require `utf8mb4`.

If you ask for `CHAR(2)` then that will allow two characters of whatever character set the column's set to.

Comment: Thank you, you explained it very well. MY thoughts exactly!

Comment: If that solves your question, mark it accepted if you like. Helps direct others with the same issue to the right solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Premature optimization.

Fetching a record is *much* more costly than virtually anything that you do *within* the row.

Almost always simply `VARCHAR(n)` where `n` is a suitable length for the data.

`CHAR(n)` is useful *only* for hex, country_code, postal_code, uuid, etc -- things that are both fixed length and `CHARACTER SET ascii`.

Sure, you could get away with one-byte `CHARACTER SET latin1` characters for French and much of Europe.  But that is such a tiny optimization that it is not worth doing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining